# Is there easy way to search in fetched records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I want to search in fetched records:

```
p = Product.added_today # Get records by scope

# wants something like
p.search(:name => 'Clocks')
```

Is there easy (rails way) to do it (gem or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Rails features to mimic that kind of search.

- In Rails 2 you can use **[Named Scopes](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-has-finder-functionality)**
- In Rails 3 you can use **[Arel](http://github.com/rails/arel)** (See the Readme section)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pa =  Product.added_today
pa.select{|p| p.name == "Clocks"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try building on your scope:
`Product.added_today.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => 'Clock'})`

Comment: This code only fetches what you want. However, if you already fetched rows, and now want to select some records, the only way I can think of is to iterate over all of them. Check amba's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be using ruby's find_all -

```
q = p.find_all{ |e| e.name == 'Clocks' }
```

as this this code uses brute force ruby array search, performance isn't great. if you expect p to contain more than a few tens of elements, using database queries would be better, performance wise.